# Is there any way to read deleted users' questions?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts

I was trying to access via Chrome's favourites links to an old question but when I try to do it, it says that the question is unavailable.

Seems that the user who asked it has deleted his/her account so the question is now also reachable with a Google search but not readable.

Is there any way to read a question even if the user who asked it deleted his/her account?

Thanks!

P.S.: Seems linke 10k+ rep users can read deleted questions. Does it concern also deleted users' questions? Should i be >10k rep?

Comment: Deleting account doesn't mean deleting all the questions. The question has to be deleted on its own, either by its author or in other way.

Comment: Anyway, your answer is in the FAQ, under "What does deletion mean for a post?"

Comment: @ShadowWizard Mhh... FAQs seems to describe deleted posts, is it the same also for a deleted account? I mean, it looks like the deletion is of the account of the person who asked, who deleted his/her account, not the single question. Is it the same concept?

Comment: It is not relevant. When a question is deleted, it doesn't matter if its author account is also deleted or not, same rules for who can or not view it apply.

Comment: @ShadowWizard All right, understood! Thanks for the explaination man! :)